# What is best way to make sure alert box doesnt pop up if an alert is already there?

Tags: javascript

In javascript, if I have an infinite loop:

```
setInterval("popalert", 5000)
```

Where `popalert()` simply pops an alert box, what is the best way to make it such that an alert box does not pop up if there is already a single alert box that has not been closed yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to detect that the alert is there.

Do not use `setInterval`, use `setTimeout`.

Reset the timeout after the alert happens.

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/JePru/)

Comment: Could you provide some short snippet of what you described? I am not sure how you would reset a setTimeout or get reference to it.

Comment: @Teiviere added a basic example.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to detect the standard javascript alert boxes as they are extremely simple. If you keep spawning them they will just queue and in modern browsers it actually gives you the option to suppress them for a certain page after a few.

I would consider using a different type notification system if having no more than 1 box at any time is important to you. Something like [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

Answer (score 0):

The popalert function could save the state of the alert box.

```
var bOpen = false;
```

then when its poped up set it true

and if it closes after pushing ok or something set it false again.

when popalert is called again it checks the bOpen var and if its true, it just doesn't open a new popup.

also I would use settimeout, so you don't get this endless loop stuff blocking your gui.

Answer (score 0):

You can't detect if an alert box is already here.
Your navigator manage this alert box, so they can't popup if another is already here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global javascript variable (out of any function) and set this var initially to false. If your popalert function is called, check if the global var is false. If so, pop your alert and set the var to true. Doing this only one alert will be shown, but your function will be executed again and again (if this is important).